# Open an Android app from a web browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, browser, view

I'm opening an app from a web browser in android and I can't seem to find the way to open this app outside the browser itself. I mean, the app opens inside the browser. I've tried both of these ways:

1) intent://pinnacle.androidApp/#Intent;scheme=launch package=my.androidApp;S.content=WebContent;end

2) my.androidapp://cb

What's the proper way to do this in order to open the app outside the browser?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

My app consists of a **native android app with a web view** that loads an **angular web app**. I think that the web browser is opening the web app instead of redirecting back to the android app with the web view.

It goes as follows:
The user opens an android app with a web view that loads an angular web app. Then the user is supposed to log in. Due to some recent changes that google implemented, I **can't log in with google from a web view**, so I have to open a web browser, log in and go back to the android app. This latter thing is the actual problem. It only works properly if the browser that I use is chrome.
I can't use android to log in because I'm using custom authentication as well to provide access to other web services.

Answer (score 0):

Register a URI scheme for your app and launch it by calling the URI somewhere as a link in your web page. This works 100%.

Comment: That's actually what I did, but it opens the app inside the web browser.

Comment: An app can not open inside a web browser. You can only open a website in there. I think you are mistaking.